# Four different python version installed

Tags: python, macos

I am starting to learn Python on my Mac and use VS Code. At the bottom left corner I can select the Python version. Apparently I have four versions installed.
[image: Installed Python versions] 
I know that macOS already has one installed (I am assuming it is the one in `/System/Library/..`). I must have (accidentally) installed the other versions.

- What is the safe/recommended way to set up Python3 on Mac for development (I only want/need **one** version 3.xx)?
- Where should I install pip3?

I don't want to mess around with the system's python version, but delete everything unnecessary.

Thank you for advice!

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` is a symlink to `/System/...bin/python2.7`. `/usr/bin/python3` shipped with Catalina. `/usr/local/bin/python3` was installed later, probably using a 3rd-party tool like Homebrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not delete python2.7 as it may be used by system. Other than that, whenever you want to create any project in python is recommended to create a virtual environment, this way you can always separate what version will every project use and what libraries will you install for a specific library. More infor https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html and how to uninstall python from mac https://osxuninstaller.com/uninstall-guides/properly-uninstall-python-mac/